# xcode 4.6.3 phonegap2.9 why the event deviceready not fire

Tags: cordova

I am a beginner of phonegap and javascript html. I don't know  why the event deviceready not fire and onload not execute. please help me, thank you.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Device</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Use an event listener to detect if PhoneGap is ready
            //
            function onLoad() {
                console.log("onload");
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            }

            // okay, PhoneGap is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("deviceReady");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <p id="props">Loading device properties...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding ondeviceready inside "onload" callback which may be dispatched after ondeviceready is dispatched.

Therefore you should bind the event directly. See example at: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
    }
</script>
```

Comment: <head>
            <title>My Device</title>
            
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"     src="phonegap.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                
                function onDeviceReady() {
                    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
                    console.log("onDeviceReady");
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p id="props">Loading device properties...</p>
        </body>